# Find local min and local max from dataset

Tags: algorithms, regression

I have a collection of data consists of TIME and TEMPERATURE as follow:

(time1, temp1), 
(time2, temp2), 
(time3, temp3), 
...
(time-n temp-n).

I cannot come up with a good computer algorithm to find the local min(s) and local max(s).
Not sure what is the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

How about if (temp1 > temp2 and temp2 < temp3) then temp2 is a local minimum?